# Eclipse Tomcat Web Deployment Assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Hi i'm trying deploy a Java EE Web Project via Eclipse on a tomcat install on localhost (Tomcat v 7 at localhost). The ultimate goal is to take use of JRebel to avoid the traditional handling of war files, and instead just press F5 in the browser the make changes in the application shine trough. However, the application has a "non-standard" folder structure, that i find hard to control using the "Web Deployment Assembly", since i can only find support for folders.

Ok, let me try to evolve, in Eclipse, i right click the Web Project, choose "Properties", and then
"Web Deployment Assembly", where it is possible to set Source folder and corresponding target folder, this is however crippling, to that extent, that i can only point to folder level.
What i would like to be able todo is, set source down to file level, since the application i'm working on has a very specific folder/file structure, which deviates from the "normal" Hello World folder/file structure of a Web Project.

Dunno if this makes it any clearer.

Ok after rubbing both of my braincells, and using the link that Anton tipped me, i got it to work out just fine.
This how i did it,

1. Create a rebel.xml file, right-click project | JRebel | Add JRebel Nature, where the settings for classpath and webfolder has to be set, http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html. View section on configure WAR.
2. Configure Server in Eclipse (Window | Show View | Servers), setting

   - Server Location to "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)
   - Server path, "/usr/local/tomcat", pointing to Tomcat install on my computer
   - Deploy path, webapps directory
3. Build a war-file in Eclipse using Ant in my case, and copying it over to the webapps directory.
4. Start up the Tomcat server from Eclipse (Window | Show View | Servers), then right-click the server instance | Start. The application will now be deployed the traditional way, check out for messages in the Eclipse console, that JRebel actually is loading as it should.
5. Now try to change in any of your jsp, css, js, model classes, service classes dao classes, or wathever structure your application has. These should now take place immediatly
   on F5 in your browser.

Again thanks for your help Anton

Comment: what is the question actually?

Comment: @AntonArhipov i just added, some hopefully more explanatory.

Comment: Still doesn't make it clearer. You didn't state what is the question _actually_. Most likely what you want to know is how to configure rebel.xml. You just need to specify the path where the compiled classes are and where the static resources are and that's it... And to place rebel.xml into WEB-INF/lib of the archive. The configuration file structure is documented here: http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html

Comment: @AntonArhipov Hi thanks for your concern, yes i want end up configuring the rebel.xml file, however, as i figure, i would have to tell Eclipse how to structure the application while deploying from Eclipse, since the application as it is today has certain preconfigured paths (struts.xml, web.xml, tiles.xml and a lot of other sub-xmls pointed to by struts.xml in order to not make IT too long, which are placed in WEB-INF), context.xml is for instance placed in META-INF, and a lot of other specific paths.

Comment: @AntonArhipov Hi again, thanks for the link, i will truly look this up, and hopefully all my problems will be solved :)

Comment: @learning Please consider posting your solution into a "real" answer.